# How to put class attribute in <c:url>?

Tags: jsp, jstl

This is the link I have

```
        <a class="btn btn-outline-light mt-3 btn-lg" href="/menu">Name</a>
```

I want to transform it to `<c:url>` to be able to use `<c:param>`

I've tried this, but it does not give me a way to put class attritbute so that my css works.

```
    <c:url value="/menu">
 <c:param name="Id" value="736"/>
 <c:param name="user" value="example"/>
</c:url>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one solution.

```
    <c:url value="/menu" context="${pageContext.request.contextPath}" var="menuUrl">
        <c:param name="Id" value="736"/>
        <c:param name="user" value="example"/>
    </c:url>
    <a class="btn btn-outline-light mt-3 btn-lg" href="${menuUrl}">Name</a>
```